# Unicode encode error: 'latin-1' in Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to program a script that retrieves XML data and then send them to my database, but I am having a problem encoding or decoding, I do not know. 
I said that I searched the internet at earlier and try different things, but this does not solve my problem. This is why I turn to you to find a solution.

Here's part of my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
...
REQ = u"INSERT INTO organismes (NAME_organisme,ID_organisme,ligne,cp,town,lat,lon,tel,fax,email,website) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute(REQ, (NAME,ID,LIGNE,CP,TOWN,LAT,LON,TEL,FAX,MAIL,URL))
cursor.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 9: ordinal not in range(255)
```

I've tryed many exemple to encode this code in utf8. My Notepad++ encode "UTF-8 without DOM".

Thx to answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem with the encoding of the source code but how `MySQLdb` handles `unicode` values.  Its default encoding is Latin-1 which is not able to encode the whole range of unicode characters.  You have to tell `MySQLdb` to use a different encoding.  There is a `charset` argument for the `connect()` function.  I would recommend using 'utf8'.

Comment: I've modifie my code of MySQLbd.connect with :

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="organismes france",charset="UTF-8")
But now, i have this error :
    2019, "Can't initialize character set UTF-8 (path:     C:\\mysql\\\\share\\charset\\)")

Comment: Sorry, the value has to be written as 'utf8'.  I've corrected that in the answer.

Comment: Ok no problem. I'll try in MySQLdb.connect(...,charset="utf8")
EDIT : THX YOU SO MUCH. It works !! Love you men :)